# Function inside an Object return "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" error

Tags: javascript

```
(function (window) {
    var speakWord = "Hello";
    var HelloSpeaker = {
        function speak(name) {
        console.log(speakWord + " " + name)}
    }
    window.HelloSpeaker = HelloSpeaker
})(window)
```

I dont know why line "function speak(name) {" returns "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error"?

Comment: You are defining a simple object (HelloSpeaker) that contains a full function definition. If you are trying to assign a function to a variable, that's not how it's done. [see this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

Answer (score 4):

You're assigning a method to the object, you should be doing that like this

`{ property: value }`, in your case the "value" would be a function

```js
(function(window) {
  var speakWord = "Hello";
  var HelloSpeaker = {
    speak: function(name) {
      console.log(speakWord + " " + name)
    }
  }
  window.HelloSpeaker = HelloSpeaker;
})(window)

window.HelloSpeaker.speak('ananth');
```